# Windows Phone Device Registration

Tags: windows-phone-8

Trying to register a windows phone 8 device for development using the development registration tool on windows 8.

Unfortunately, it says that I have to verify the account using a code. Problem is the code is being sent to an email that is not active. Is there any way I can change the account that it selects to send the code to? It just automatically says it will send a code to this email account.

I've tried restarting the machine and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but, First you have to reactive that account. Just sign in normally as an active account it will ask you that are you sure want to reactivate your account ? check yes and after that you can change your secondary account from settings.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess the microsoft account that was signed in was connected to this inactive account - signed into a different one and was able to register the device.